# How to pass data in react js sever side rendering using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, server-side-rendering

I have created react application using redux that is working fine. But now I want to implement SSR. Although I have implemented SSR and that is working but on page load, I want to render that with data but its rendered without data.
How can I render my page with initial data in SSR?

Comment: Can you provide some code? A typical issue is hydrating the data that you want to be rendered on the screen. Are you doing that?

Comment: What action do you dispatch to get the data and how do you get the data (thunk, saga).

Comment: I am not using any middleware.

Comment: This is my code for hydrating:
ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <Provider store={store}>
      <AppRoutes />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);